# Listview is showing only one row when showing json data in android

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm trying to show json data in listview in android. I'm getting json data perfectly but when i'm trying to show it in listview just getting only one row.
And i want to show data of each row in an activity as per item click. Here i'm not understanding how to pass the data from json depending on which item is clicked.

here is my code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List list = new ArrayList();
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}
public void add(DataProvider dataProvider) {
    super.add(dataProvider);
    list.add(dataProvider);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    dataProviderHolder holder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);
        holder = new dataProviderHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.subject = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.subject);
        holder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tim);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (dataProviderHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    DataProvider provider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
    holder.name.setText(provider.getName());
    holder.subject.setText(provider.getSubject());
    holder.date.setText(provider.getDate());
    holder.time.setText(provider.getTime());
    return row;
}

static class dataProviderHolder {
    TextView name, subject, date, time;
}
}
```

Json parsing :

```
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
    json_string = user.get(SessionManager.JSON_STRING);
    try {

        String name, subject, message, date, time;
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("message");
        int count = 0;
        while (count < jsonObject.length()) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            name = object.getString("name");
            subject = object.getString("subject");
            message = object.getString("message");
            date = object.getString("date");
            time = object.getString("time");
            sessionManager.getJsonMesssage(message);
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name, subject, date, time);
            customAdapter.add(dataProvider);
            count++;
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
                    String message = user.get(SessionManager.JSON_MESSAGE);
                    Intent i = new Intent(MessageList.this, MessageDetails.class);
                    i.putExtra("message", message);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you are getting only one data so only it shows only one data

Comment: have you tried customAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged() after adding item ???

Comment: +1 to @SujithNiraikulathan, add `notifyDatasetChanged();` as last (after `list.add()`) line in adapter's method `add(DataProvider )`, also add a `Log.i()` in the while loop to make sure how many items were added to the adapter, maybe you are getting 1 item in the json, also as per Nirup answer below move the `setOnItemClickListener()` after the while loop

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not put listview.setOnItemClickListener in a loop. That does nothing. Instead add it in your getView() method of adapter.`

```
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
                String message = user.get(SessionManager.JSON_MESSAGE);
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MessageDetails.class);
                i.putExtra("message", message);
                startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Then, set your adapter after adding all the list items in while loop.

Comment: I,m not getting all the item on listview.